Did Archimedes really think of himself as a 'pure' mathematician first and foremost?
And did Archimedes really hate applied mathematics, as Plutarch's writings suggest?
If the contents of Plutarch's book are true, were Archimedes' various engineering inventions not purely intellectual pursuits, but simply made at the king's command?

Some people describe him as a physicist, some as an engineer, everybody wants him on their side.

In his time, the notion of applied math did not exist. It is actually relatively recent.

The concept of 'applied mathematics' is anachronistic when misapplied to the work of ancient Hellenistic times. For example Ptolemy's big work on astronomy (nicknamed 'Almagest') was formally entitled 'Mathematical Compilation' (the Greek transliterates as 'mathematike syntaxis'). Mathematics permeated a number of activities, and their boundaries were not as we now imagine them.

Do diagrams in the sand count as applications?  Because those were reportedly the literal death of him.

How can we possibly know what Archimedes thought?

It is hard to know Archimedes's views given scarce and conflicting evidence that we have. Plutarch reports on Archimedes in the context of describing Plato's criticism of mechanical methods in geometry introduced by Archytas and Eudoxus "on the ground that they destroyed and corrupted the good of geometry, which relapses from incorporeal, intelligible objects to sensibles", see When were the concepts of pure and applied Mathematics introduced? He writes:

"Archimedes had designed and contrived these machines (mêchanêmata), not as matters
of any importance, but as mere amusements in geometry; in compliance with King
Hiero's desire and request, some little time before, that he should turn something of
his art (technê) from intelligible to bodily things, and by combining theory (logos) with
use (chreia) through sense perception (aisthêsis), bring it more within the appreciation
of the people in general."

There is a similar passage in Pappus conveying the testimony of Carpus of Antioch:

"But Carpus of Antioch says somewhere that Archimedes the Syracusan composed
only one book on mechanics (mêchanikon), the one on sphere-making, and did not
think it worth writing about any of the other [branches]. And yet that wondrous and
great-natured man, with such a reputation for mechanics (mêchanikê) among many
that he continues to be exceedingly praised by all people, wrote down zealously even
things that seemed to be very trivial concerning anything connected with the principal subjects of geometry and arithmetic. Clearly, he so loved the aforementioned sciences
that he did not suffer anything external to be brought into them."

However, it is unclear how much of this reflects genuine attitude of Archimedes as opposed to efforts of later platonists, like Plutarch, to reconcile one of the foremost authorities in geometry with Plato's 'purified' view of the subject. It is odd, for example, that Carpus is either unaware of Archimedes's On the Equilibrium of Planes and On Floating Bodies or does not consider them to be "on mechanics". Analysis of Archimedes's letter to Eratosthenes on 'mechanical theorems', and presentation of his work in Heron's Metrica also suggests a later platonist gloss of his work, see  Boscarino,  Archimedes’  to Eratosthenes in the Palimpsest and Archimedes in Heron’s Metrikon:

"The picture that emerges from the reading of the Heronian work about Archimedes is certainly that of an author interested in works of proofs, but is especially the image wider of an author interested in physical operations of measurements, and for this inventor of measurement methods, not stopping at methods of measurements of regular, perfect forms, according to the Platonic image, passed down by Plutarch, but going beyond, to the measurement of the most irregular, empirical forms, not just ideals, inventing appropriate methods for them, though not rigorous, approximate...  The Archimedes by Heron appears in short more a Pythagorean, interested in the mathematical number, ratio of magnitudes, than in the ideal, existing in itself, metaphysical number, of Platonic ascendance, which was what divided the Pythagoreans from the Platonists according to testimony of Aristotle... In short yet in Heron as in the Archimedes the mathema is not conceived as pure abstraction in the Aristotelian sense, divorced from the relationship with the physical world, or pure ideal, metaphysical existence in the Platonic sense, but the relationship between physical entities, magnitudes."

That mathematicians in Plato's time and later were not overly impressed by his strictures about 'intelligibles' is attested to by proliferation of 'mechanical' methods in geometry from Archytas and Menaechmus to Archimedes, Apollonius and Diocles, and their explicit defense by Pappus against Plato in the paragraph following the one about Archimedes:

"But Carpus himself and some others made use of geometry also for some crafts
(technai), with reason: for geometry is not harmed at all by associating with them, as it
is naturally suited to give body to them. Accordingly, being as it were mother of the
crafts, it is not harmed by giving thought to the building of instruments [of war]
(organikê) and architecture, nor is it harmed at all by associating with land measurement
and gnomonics and scene-painting; on the contrary it clearly causes
these to advance, while being honored and adorned (kosmoumenê) by them."

